# populate array list from For loop using entire database table row

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, gridview, arraylist

I am trying check my `Events` table for DateTime overlaps in each of the events.  I have written code that will allow a user to input a `Module_code`.  This `Module_code` is checked against the entries in the `Events` table.  If `Start_Date_Time` or `End_Date_Time` for any of the events overlap with the `Start_Date_Time` or `End_Date_Time` of any other event in the table, for that module only, then I want to put the event row into an array list and later populate a gridview with the results.  I have the following code, which I think achieves most of my goals.  However when I run it the gridview there is no data in it.  Debug shows that nothing was sent to it.  I presume it is a problem with how I am trying to pass my values to the arrayList.

```
    'return all relevant tables from the Modules database, based on the module code entered by the user.
    Dim eventTime = (From mods In db.Modules
                    Join evnt In db.Events On mods.Module_code Equals evnt.Module_code
                    Join rm In db.Rooms On rm.Room_ID Equals evnt.Room_ID
                    Join build In db.Buildings On build.Building_code Equals rm.Building_code
                    Where ((mods.Module_code = initialModCode) And (evnt.Room_ID = rm.Room_ID))
                    Select evnt.Event_ID, evnt.Module_code, evnt.Event_type, evnt.Start_Date_Time, evnt.End_Date_Time, build.Building_code, rm.Room_Number)


    Dim listClashes As New ArrayList()

    For i As Integer = 0 To eventTime.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = i + 1 To eventTime.Count - 1
            If (eventTime.ToList(i).Start_Date_Time < eventTime.ToList(j).End_Date_Time) And (eventTime.ToList(i).End_Date_Time > eventTime.ToList(j).Start_Date_Time) Then
                'MsgBox("Clash", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground, "")
                listClashes.Add(eventTime)
            Else
                'MsgBox("No Clash", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground, "")
            End If
        Next
    Next

    gdvClashes.DataSource = listClashes
    gdvClashes.DataBind()
```

EDIT..Code changed to

```
 If (eventTime(i).Start_Date_Time <= eventTime(j).End_Date_Time) And (eventTime(i).End_Date_Time >= eventTime(j).Start_Date_Time) Then
                'MsgBox("Clash", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground, "")
                listClashes.Add(eventTime.ToList)
            Else
```

This edit has not worked.  It is throwing an exception to say that `The query operator 'ElementAtOrDefault' is not supported.`  Am I going in the totally wrong direction here?

EDIT..

New code suggestion

```
   Dim listClashes = From e1 In eventTime
                       From e2 In eventTime
                       Where (e2.Start_Date_Time >= e1.Start_Date_Time) And (e2.Start_Date_Time <= e1.End_Date_Time)
                       Select eventTime

    gdvClashes.DataSource = listClashes
    gdvClashes.DataBind()
```

Should this be enclosed in a for loop or referencing an arrayList or something?

Comment: hi @GertArnold.  Yes the issue remains.  I could be doing the total opposite of what I am supposed to here.  I'm a novice so I'm working of a hit and hope method while researching on MSDN and a few books as best I can, but I can't get to what I'm meant to do here.  It's hard to get simplified answers to things like the exact function of ArrayList, ToList etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested loop is only confusing. You can do everything in one query:

```
Dim listClashes = 
    From e1 in eventTime
    From e2 in eventTime
    Where e2.Start_Date > e1.Start_Date && e2.Start_Date < e1.End_Date
    Select (...)
```

Which is: you find events that have their start date between the startdate and enddate of other events.

Since `eventTime` is an `IQueryable` the whole statement `listClashes` is translated to one SQL query and in the end the database engine does all the hard work and your client code only receives the results.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I will be kicked off here one day for asking to many questions or not understanding an answer so I apologise in advance.  Please see my edited question to see my current code now.  `Dim listClashes` naturally returns all values.  I cannot print these out as VS says `Range variable eventTime hides a variable in an enclosing block.  I know this is because I am returning potentially infinite results.  I don't know how to make this an acceptable statement, short of doing `select eventTime.first` which naturally defeats the purpose.

Comment: `Select e1` or `Select e2` should do it.

Comment: It's close.  Only problem is that when I return the gridview it will return the overlapping result twice and say, for example `event 11` overlaps with `event 12`, if I select to return `e1` then `event 12` will not be displayed so I am only showing one of the conflicting events, not what it conflicts with.  I'm sure that is a more difficult query though.  Anyway you have given me enough of your time tonight (in Europe) so I will try and work it out.  Thank you @Gert Arnold